# I need a query to get output as mention below

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the data in the table as below.

```
cntrct_number   status_cd   registration_date
123             A           23-03-19
123             A           06-06-19
123             S           10-06-21
123             S           11-06-21
123             S           12-06-21
123             A           13-06-21
123             S           14-06-21
123             S           15-06-21
```

Now I want the two minimum dates of status_cd = 'S'
like the query should give the output as below.

```
123             S           11-06-21
123             S           14-06-21
```

The output is that when the status is changed then it should take the first row immediate after the change of status.

Comment: What is the criteria for minimum within status_cd?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use where to filter the result by status, then order it by date, and the last step limit the output by 2 rows:

```
select * from table where status_cd = 'S' order by registration_date limit 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

What we're looking for is a qualification in a window function.

Qualification 1: the status code is S.
Qualification 2: the previous status code is not S.

```
create or replace transient table T1(cntrct_number int, status_cd string, registration_date date);

insert into T1 (cntrct_number, status_cd, registration_date) values
(123,             'A',           to_date('23-03-19', 'DD-MM-YY')),
(123,             'A',           to_date('06-06-19', 'DD-MM-YY')),
(123,             'S',           to_date('10-06-21', 'DD-MM-YY')),
(123,             'S',           to_date('11-06-21', 'DD-MM-YY')),
(123,             'S',           to_date('12-06-21', 'DD-MM-YY')),
(123,             'A',           to_date('13-06-21', 'DD-MM-YY')),
(123,             'S',           to_date('14-06-21', 'DD-MM-YY')),
(123,             'S',           to_date('15-06-21', 'DD-MM-YY'));


select   cntrct_number
        ,status_cd
        ,registration_date
from    T1
qualify STATUS_CD = 'S' 
    and lag(STATUS_CD) over (partition by cntrct_number order by registration_date) <> 'S'
;
```